# converting class file to jar file using c++

Tags: java, c++

Is it possible to convert `.class` file to `.jar` file using c++ code?

**(i.e  can we write a code in c++ that when executed converts given .class file to .jar file)**

If yes,how can i do that?

Comment: You may find it simpler to run `jar` via exec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A .jar file is just ZIP archive containing .class files and possibly a manifest file. (The most important part of the manifest file is the name of the class to run with `java -jar`.) You can generate a .jar file quite easily in C++ from the .class file, by using a library which can generate ZIP archive files.

If you don't care about the size savings because of compression in the ZIP file, you can easily create an uncompressed ZIP file, even without using a library. The ZIP format is documented e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29